# Apache POI Java Excel Performance for Large Spreadsheets

Tags: java, performance, excel, apache-poi

I have a spreadsheet I'm trying to read with POI (I have both xls and xlsx formats), but in this case, the problem is with the xls file. My spreadsheet has about 10,000 rows and 75 columns, and reading it in can take several minutes (though Excel opens in a few seconds). I'm using the event based reading, rather than reading the whole file into memory. The meat of my code is below. It's a bit messy right now, but it's really just a long switch statement that was mostly copied from the POI examples.

Is it typical for POI performance using the event model to be so slow? Is there anything I an do to speed this up? I think several minutes will be unacceptable for my application.

```
    POIFSFileSystem poifs = new POIFSFileSystem(fis);
    InputStream din = poifs.createDocumentInputStream("Workbook");
    try
    {
        HSSFRequest req = new HSSFRequest();
        listener = new FormatTrackingHSSFListener(new HSSFListener() {
            @Override
            public void processRecord(Record rec)
            {
                thisString = null;
                int sid = rec.getSid();
                switch (sid)
                {
                    case SSTRecord.sid:
                        strTable = (SSTRecord) rec;
                        break;
                    case LabelSSTRecord.sid:
                        LabelSSTRecord labelSstRec = (LabelSSTRecord) rec;
                        thisString = strTable.getString(labelSstRec
                                .getSSTIndex()).getString();
                        row = labelSstRec.getRow();
                        col = labelSstRec.getColumn();
                        break;
                    case RKRecord.sid:
                        RKRecord rrk = (RKRecord) rec;
                        thisString = "";
                        row = rrk.getRow();
                        col = rrk.getColumn();
                        break;
                    case LabelRecord.sid:
                        LabelRecord lrec = (LabelRecord) rec;
                        thisString = lrec.getValue();
                        row = lrec.getRow();
                        col = lrec.getColumn();
                        break;
                    case BlankRecord.sid:
                        BlankRecord blrec = (BlankRecord) rec;
                        thisString = "";
                        row = blrec.getRow();
                        col = blrec.getColumn();
                        break;
                    case BoolErrRecord.sid:
                        BoolErrRecord berec = (BoolErrRecord) rec;
                        row = berec.getRow();
                        col = berec.getColumn();
                        byte errVal = berec.getErrorValue();
                        thisString = errVal == 0 ? Boolean.toString(berec
                                .getBooleanValue()) : ErrorConstants
                                .getText(errVal);
                        break;
                    case FormulaRecord.sid:
                        FormulaRecord frec = (FormulaRecord) rec;
                        switch (frec.getCachedResultType())
                        {
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                double num = frec.getValue();
                                if (Double.isNaN(num))
                                {
                                    // Formula result is a string
                                    // This is stored in the next record
                                    outputNextStringRecord = true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    thisString = formatNumericValue(frec, num);
                                }
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                thisString = Boolean.toString(frec
                                        .getCachedBooleanValue());
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                                thisString = HSSFErrorConstants
                                        .getText(frec.getCachedErrorValue());
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                outputNextStringRecord = true;
                                break;
                        }
                        row = frec.getRow();
                        col = frec.getColumn();
                        break;
                    case StringRecord.sid:
                        if (outputNextStringRecord)
                        {
                            // String for formula
                            StringRecord srec = (StringRecord) rec;
                            thisString = srec.getString();
                            outputNextStringRecord = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case NumberRecord.sid:
                        NumberRecord numRec = (NumberRecord) rec;
                        row = numRec.getRow();
                        col = numRec.getColumn();
                        thisString = formatNumericValue(numRec, numRec
                                .getValue());
                        break;
                    case NoteRecord.sid:
                        NoteRecord noteRec = (NoteRecord) rec;
                        row = noteRec.getRow();
                        col = noteRec.getColumn();
                        thisString = "";
                        break;
                    case EOFRecord.sid:
                        inSheet = false;
                }
                if (thisString != null)
                {
                    // do something with the cell value 
                }
            }
        });
        req.addListenerForAllRecords(listener);
        HSSFEventFactory factory = new HSSFEventFactory();
        factory.processEvents(req, din);
```

Comment: Is it xls that is slow and xlsx that works fine? For me it is opposite, writing a file with many rows just uses some megabytes of heap for xls, but even 2GB wasn't enough for xlsx. I need to fallback to xls if output has more than X rows

Comment: @rlovtang, xlsx is even slower. I just meant I am using POI instead of something like JExcel because I need to deal with both xls and xlsx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did also some processing with thousands of large excel files and in my opinion POI is very fast. Loading that excel files tooks also about 1 minute in Excel itself. So i would confirm that the problem lies out of POI code

Answer (score 19):

f you are using Apache POI to generate large excel file, please take note the following line :

`sheet.autoSizeColumn((short) p);`

Because this will degrade the performance.

Comment: _How_ will it impact performance? Will it help or will it hinder it?

Comment: This really helped me out, I was running a simple 3000 line output taking 10 minutes down to 2 seconds (literally).  You will notice this issue as your code slows down on the write out.  Thanks @sams

Answer (score 3):

I would attempt to use the streaming hssf as well introduced in poi-beta3.  This helped the memory issues on large spreadsheets with 1000+ columns.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Apache POI to generate large excel file, please take note the sheet.autoSizeColumn((short) p); line because this will impact the performance.

http://stanicblog.blogspot.sg/2013/07/generate-large-excel-report-by-using.html

Comment: This may not be true because in the article autoSizeColumn is called in a loop as every row is being added, and not after the loop once all the rows are done.

Answer (score 1):

I did some more detailed profiling and it looks like the problem is actually in code outside of POI. I just assumed this was the bottleneck, but I believe this is incorrect.

Comment: Can you provide more detail into where the code was?  Was it your own code, or 3rd party jars?

Comment: It was my own code. I was mistakenly trying to do some very inefficient parsing of text fields to see if they had date values (for when users entered text dates into cells that did not have a date format).