# Excel parser JSP Spring

Tags: excel, spring-mvc

I have been wondering if anyone could suggest me a good java Excel parser so I can upload and manipulate XLS files easily in spring. There are some parser on the internet but I don't know which one is the lightest and fastest. I just need a simple one.

Thanks alot....

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why not just use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) - I've never had any performance related problems with it - I've been generating reports with tens of thousands rows and POI has never been a bottleneck. Besides that Spring provides [AbstractExcelView](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/document/AbstractExcelView.html) for excel views.

see [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498536/poi-performance) and
[question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992536/apache-poi-java-excel-performance-for-large-spreadsheets)