# Read excel records of 400k rows in java quickly

Tags: java, spring, performance, apache-poi, file-processing

I would like to read excel file of 400k rows max using java or spring efficiently.Right now we are using Apache POI to read files  and process it took more than 15 minutes . 
Iam running out of ideas , Can anyone please help me process this huge file efficiently using Java related tech stack ?

EDIT : IS there a way to sort rows based on a particular Integer column , with a minimum memory usage using Apache POI.

Comment: post your code.

Comment: Try streaming: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33786219/apache-poi-streaming-sxssf-for-reading

Comment: Just as an idea: Try to profile the poi code. Maybe you create too much objects and you have issues with memory allocation or something? Or maybe your loop is inefficient... When asking a question like "look my code is slow" - you should know where does it spend its time exactly...

Comment: According to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992536/apache-poi-java-excel-performance-for-large-spreadsheets?rq=1 - Apache POI works efficiently at least with reading a file. So, the problem mostly lies out of POI code.

Comment: try Excel Streaming Reader -> https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader

Comment: Thank you Very much , i am able to process 500k records under 2 mins using the above library.

Comment: IS there a way to sort rows based on a particular Integer column , with a minimum memory usage for 500k records using Apache POI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OPCPackage](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/OPCPackage.html) and [XSSFReader](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XSSFReader.html) class. It has less memory footprint. For sorting you can use HashMap with your own custom Comparable.
You can see the example source here [link](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage)